# Where can I find "SIP Communicator" library

Tags: android, java, sip

I'm developing Sip Client for Android. And I need this library to complete my project. there is an open source code using this library but i can't find it anywhere

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A well-known open-source Android SIP client [CSipSimple](http://code.google.com/p/csipsimple/) relies on [PJSIP](http://www.pjsip.org/) which has a dual, GPL + probably commercial, license.

Comment: i have tried a lot with pjsip but the sample app apjsua is not working.... have you done that then please help me.

Answer (score 0):

As of Android 2.3 I believe, there is `android.net.sip` included in the SDK.

Comment: but this only works on wifi and you can't change codec with this..... do you know any way to use this on other than wifi than it will be a great help for me.

Answer (score 0):

jain sip works on android 1.6 but i cannot implement it in android 2.3 and above.